# When do I use @OneToOne annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have two tables `table1`, `table2`. Both have a one to one relation.

`table2` contains foreign key of `table1`.

If I use 
`@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` or
`@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` for the method below. Then what will be the effect of it?

```
@Column( name = "table1_id" )
public Long getTable1Id() {
    return this.table1Id;

}
```

Comment: I find it helps to think in terms of object instead of tables. So how would you link two objects together? Well, one would have to be a member of the other. Dbf has more on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OneToOne than you need to define not id variable in class, but object of another class, like in these examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html.

Lazy means that row from other table will not be fetched until accessed.
`CascadeType.ALL` means that all operations (like delete) will be propagated to associated object.

Comment: Currently I can succesfully fetch and save records. If I apply @OneToOne( cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY ) then will it through exception?

Comment: Declaring it will definitely don't throw an exception - but I guess you mean when accessing it? Firstly, @OneToOne ist correct for a one-to-one realtion of course and secondly, you will get an exception complaining about lazy loading if you try to access the getter/setter while not being in a valid persistence context, meaning your references to the other objects cannot be obtained when your objects are detached.